# Change 3D view in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to change the view of a 3D plot in matlab such that the `y`-axis points upward and the `z`-axis points to left. For example, consider the following plot:

[image]

Here the `x`-axis points forward, the `y`-axis points to the right and the `z`-axis points upward.

I would like to have the `y`-axis points upward and the `z`-axis points to the left instead. I tried to rotate the plot (using the figure window toolbar rotate button) but I could not get it to work. (It should just be a simple 90 degrees rotation about the `x`-axis)

Code to generate the plot:

```
  membrane
  view(100,50)
  xlabel('x-axis');
  ylabel('y-axis');
  zlabel('z-axis');
  grid on
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using [`view`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/view.html). I don't have MATLAB available so I can't test it, but I think it can do what you want.

Example from the documentation:

> Set the view along the y-axis, with the x-axis extending horizontally
>   and the z-axis extending vertically in the figure.
>
> ```
> view([0 0]);
> ```

**EDIT:**

Try using three inputs to the `view` function. I can't experiment myself, but you should be able to do it if you choose the right values here.

From documentation:

> `view([x,y,z])` sets the view direction to the Cartesian coordinates x,
>   y, and z. The magnitude of (x,y,z) is ignored.

**EDIT 2:**

Check out [`camroll`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/camroll.html). I think `camroll(90)` (possibly in combination with `view`) will work.

From documentation:

> `camroll(dtheta)` rotates the camera around the camera viewing axis by
>   the amounts specified in dtheta (in degrees). The viewing axis is the
>   line passing through the camera position and the camera target.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not to achieve what I wanted.. Now I get a 2D-view, with the `x`-axis pointing to the right and the `z`-axis pointing upward.. I need a 3D view as in the figure in my question.

Comment: Ok I will try that.. but which values should i choose for `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: I have tried these values: `[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 1]` but none of them seem to work..

Comment: Thanks, `camroll` did work :) .. There seem to be some problems with labelling of the axis though..

Comment: Here is the result: http://imgur.com/pPuTb9T Note that the labelling of the axis are really strange..

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I'm sorry but I can't help you. I suggest you ask a new question showing how you rotate the plot, include the picture, and ask if it's possible to adjust the labels. I guess you will have a better chance of getting an answer that way.

Answer (score 4):

This was posted a while ago, but in case someone else is looking for ways to set y-axis as the vertical one here is a possible fix.

*Manually*: In the command window type cameratoolbar('show') which will open an interactive toolbar in your plot from which you could change the view. One of the options is to set a principle axis to `x`, `y`, or `z`.

Or in you script you could use cameratoolbar('SetCoordSys',coordsys) command which sets the principal axis of the camera motion. coordsys can be: `x`, `y`, `z`, or `none`.

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cameratoolbar.html